# Why does my function return the previous values and not the new ones when I call it recursively?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've to write a program that starts 2 players, passes to each player the same Dealer instance. After dealing 7 tiles for each player, each player shall print his list of tiles to a text file whose name is player’s number.

Now, in a domino game two players cannot have the same tiles, i.e. (Player 1 : 2,4 AND Player 2: 4,2).

I have used a 2D array of boolean flags to keep this in check, however whenever I print the lists out I find that 2 or more players have the same tiles. Also, please note that I have to use threads in order to represent the players.

This is my Player's run method. Each player should get 7 tiles.

```
public synchronized void run() {

try {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Player " + player + ".txt")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int a = r.nextInt(6);
            int b = r.nextInt(6);
            System.out.println("Player " + player + " is requesting a tile");
            DominoTiles dealt = dealer.deal(a, b);
            tiles[i] = dealt;

            writer.println("Requesting Player " + player + ": ");
            writer.println("Side 1 = " + tiles[i].getSide1() + " Side 2 = " + tiles[i].getSide2());

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

}
```

**This is my Dealer's deal method. I return the function if it goes in the if block, and call it again if it goes in the else if block. The problem is, I return the values that make the function go into the else if block!**

```
 public synchronized DominoTiles deal(int a, int b) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
DominoTiles dealt = new DominoTiles(a, b);
System.out.println("Dealer is dealing");

if ((count < 28 && check[a][b] == false)) {
    System.out.println("Checking " + a + " " + b + ": " + check[a][b]);

    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " has been dealt");

    check[a][b] = true;
    check[b][a] = true;
    System.out.println("Checking now : " + check[a][b]);
    count++;
    System.out.println("Count = " + count);

} else if ((count < 28 && (check[a][b] == true || check[b][a] == true)) || (check[b][a] == true)) {
    System.out.println("I tried to deal the same again!" + a + " " + b + " and it was " + check[a][b] + " " + check[b][a
            ]);
    int c = r.nextInt(7);
    int d = r.nextInt(7);
    deal(c, d);
} else {
    System.out.println("All tiles have been dealt");
    System.exit(0);
}

return dealt;

}
```

Comment: If you can make this executable it will be easier for us to find out what the problem is.  It's easier to read code when executing

Comment: By executable, do you mean to show the output?

Comment: Why are you recursing at all, rather than just looping? And it's generally a bad idea to make a method call `System.exit(0)`. Throw an exception instead...

Comment: Your approach is not good anyway. You shouldn't try to fix that - just let it die. Create a `List` with every possible tile and then draw a random tile from that list by removing it from the list. This is possible, because you have a very limited amount of possible tiles.

Comment: Here's a way better algorithm. shuffled = Collections.shuffle(range_of_numbers) player_1_random_1 = shuffled[0], player_1_random_2 = shuffled[1], player_2_random_1 = random.select(Collections.shuffle(shuffled.slice(2,n))), player_2_random_2 = random.select(Collections.shuffle(range_of_numbers_without_player_2_random_1)); This is not java code btw...just pseudo code, but you get the idea. No ugly loops or recursion required.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I'll take care of that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you aren't assigning the result of the recursive call to deal() to the dealt variable.

To fix:

```
public synchronized DominoTiles deal(int a, int b) throws  FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    DominoTiles dealt = new DominoTiles(a, b);
    System.out.println("Dealer is dealing");

    if ((count < 28 && check[a][b] == false)) {
        System.out.println("Checking " + a + " " + b + ": " + check[a][b]);

        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " has been dealt");

        check[a][b] = true;
        check[b][a] = true;
        System.out.println("Checking now : " + check[a][b]);
        count++;
        System.out.println("Count = " + count);


    } else if ((count < 28 && (check[a][b] == true || check[b][a] == true)) || (check[b][a] == true)) {
        System.out.println("I tried to deal the same again!" + a + " " + b + " and it was " + check[a][b] + " " + check[b][a
        ]);
        int c = r.nextInt(7);
        int d = r.nextInt(7);
        dealt = deal(c, d);
    } else {
        System.out.println("All tiles have been dealt");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return dealt;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark any variables that can be used across threads as volatile for starters.

Comment: The method is synchronized - this isn't the problem

Comment: Synchronization only makes the variables be "flushed" when entering and exiting the synchronization phase. Based on the sample, I don't see a solid guarantee that this is good enough. It might be, but we are not seeing a full picture.